# How to check whether the items are unique in an array using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, performance

If you have an array with primitive values as per below;

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 45, 4, 66, 3];
```

Is there a more *efficient* way to check whether all the items are unique rather than iterating all items as below?

```
let newArr = [];
let isUnique = true;
arr.forEach(item => 
{
   if(newArr.indexOf(item) != -1)
   {
       isUnique = false;
       break;
   }
   newArray.push(item);
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An `indexOf` in a `forEach` is `O(n ^ 2)`. I'd use a Set instead - `Set.has` is `O(1)` (overall complexity of `O(n)`):

```
const allAreUnique = (arr) => {
  const set = new Set();
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (set.has(item)) return false;
    set.add(item);
  }
  return true;
};
```

```js
const allAreUnique = (arr) => {
  const set = new Set();
  for (const item of arr) {
    if (set.has(item)) return false;
    set.add(item);
  }
  return true;
};
console.log(allAreUnique([1, 2, 3, 4, 45, 4, 66, 3]));
console.log(allAreUnique([1, 2, 3, 4, 45, 66]));
```

Comment: Looks like the return is always `true`. The question requires knowing whether all the items are unique.

Comment: @SamSirry The code looks correct to me. If you run the snippet the first test returns `false` as expected.

Comment: Thank you @CertainPerformance for the prompt answer. Appreciate it!

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code. Probably something was wrong with morning coffee... Thank you for your insight @MichaelGeary